# could i connect my laptop with dish TV setup box through HDMI port

Tags: windows-vista

i tried my setup box to play over laptop(lenovo G560) with HDMI port, but it did'nt work at all, please suggest is there any third party tool to use setup box(dish TV) with my laptop (lenovo G560).
if anyone have solution please help us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Satellite TV on my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/124620/satellite-tv-on-my-pc), [Watching satellite tv from laptop's monitor](http://superuser.com/questions/605525/watching-satellite-tv-from-laptops-monitor), [Use Dish Network with a TV tuner: how?](http://superuser.com/questions/434827/use-dish-network-with-a-tv-tuner-how?lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HDMI port on your laptop (Lenovo G560) is for output only. You can output the laptops display to a TV or monitor over HDMI, but you can't accept an incoming signal on the HTMI. There are a few laptops on the market with 2 HTMI ports on them, HDMI In and HDMI Out, but yours is not one of them.

Comment: thanks bob for your solution, is there any third party tools to use laptops HDMI port with setup box.